# mysql query for date difference

Tags: mysql

I have a table record where I am storing records of time like this:

```
login_time
---------------
2010-12-08 13:40:57
2010-12-08 13:28:57
2010-12-08 13:10:57
2010-12-08 12:01:57
2010-12-08 11:05:57
```

I am using MySQL. I want to write a query to get all records which are less that "15 MINUTES" from current time.

can anyone help me out writting that query?

Comment: What is the Data Type of `login_time` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Notice: don't write `INTERVAL 15 MINUTES`. It has to be `MINUTE`.

Comment: Alternatively, to select rows where `login_time` is within 15 minutes *either side* of now: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE login_time < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND login_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);`

Comment: I don't this his app is using logins in the future :-)